# nutch: searching with key word

Tags: search, keyword, nutch

Using Nutch, I would like to crawl all http://www.amazon.com/ webpages which have ipod in their url.

For e.g if my search for ipod in their search box, I get

http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=ipod&x=0&y=0

This webpage shows a bunch of links for ipod. I would like to crawl each link which is related to ipod and get it.

The first link that shows under the search results is

[http://www.amazon.com/Apple-iPod-touch-8GB-Generation/dp/B001FA1O0O/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1319863311&sr=8-](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B001FA1O0O)

Should I use below?

```
+^http://([a-z0-9\-A-Z]*\.)*www.amazon.com/*ipod*
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to crawl this specific urls you should include following line in crawl-urlfilter.txt

```
-.*
```

this command will exclude all other urls!

Comment: Can you please add some link where more information about this is given.